# toggleClass removes on new page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made my links look like tabs which is really a filter. Here is the part in question:

```
<div class="submenu">
  <div class="row d-flex flex-items-md-between">
      <div class="col-md-8 flex-md-bottom">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tab active" href="/admin/gifts?filter=review" role="tab">Review</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tab" href="/admin/gifts?filter=accepted-redeemed" role="tab">Redeemed</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('ul.nav-tabs a').click(function () {
    // event.preventDefault();
    $('.nav-link tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

});
```

So when I 'click' on the 'tab' which goes to a new page, what happens is that the new active is applied, the old one is not removed than when it reloads the original Review has the active applied and not the Redeemed. How can I fix this?

If I add event in the callback and run event.preventDefault(); it doesn't goto the new page.

Here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/poxobejowe/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Instead of `$('.nav-link tab').removeClass('active');` try `$('.active').removeClass('active');`

Comment: Yea, I just actually did that too and it did remove the old click but on a the pageload it goes back to active. I have an idea though.

Comment: @JosephChambers Something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does reset when the page is reloaded. What you can do is, you can use Cookies or LocalStorage (my favourite) to store the state and read the state data and redo it. A simple snippet will be:

```js
$(function () {
  $("div").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    localStorage.setItem("state", (($("div").hasClass("on")) ? "on" : "off"));
    console.log("Local Storage Set to: " + (($("div").hasClass("on")) ? "on" : "off"));
  });
  if (!!localStorage.getItem("state") && localStorage.getItem("state") == "on")
    $("div").addClass("on");
  else if (!!localStorage.getItem("state") && localStorage.getItem("state") != "on")
    $("div").removeClass("on");
});
```

```css
.on .n {display: inline;}
.n,
.on .f {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click to toggle</p>
<div class="on">
  <span class="n">On</span>
  <span class="f">Off</span>
</div>
```

The above snippet is sandboxed. Please check out [**JSBin Output**](http://output.jsbin.com/goduwojite).

Comment: Thanks, your example makes since and I'm trying to get it working.

Comment: @JosephChambers Let's make it work together. Does the JSBin Output work?

Comment: Not at all. even if I copy and paste and add change the classes to reflect mine, it doesnt work.

Comment: @JosephChambers Wait... I am asking, do this. Open the JSBin link. Click on On and it turns Off. Right? Reloading the page, does it retain?

Comment: I'm creating a jsbin now.

Comment: @JosephChambers Okay, waiting... `:D`

Comment: Hey, I created a jsbin http://jsbin.com/poxobejowe/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @JosephChambers Checking. Was expecting this answer will be accepted today within 8 more mins. LoL.

Comment: @JosephChambers Works man: http://jsbin.com/dusewipuqu/1/edit You need to understand how it works.

Comment: @JosephChambers The day got over! `:(`

Comment: your code almost works. On the new page load it the first active isn't removed. Its removed when I click on other tabs but on the new pageload it comes back

Comment: @JosephChambers That's what was your question right? Page load it should come?

Comment: I figured it out. I marked your answer as the answer. How do I add a default localStorage as I removed active as a default at all.

Comment: @JosephChambers `if (!localStorage.getItem("state")) localStorage.setItem("state", "initial-state-something?");`

Comment: Thank you! You're awesome. Im saving this as a snippet :)